# Magento change backgrounds per session

Tags: session, magento, background

I'm looking for a simple extension that allows via admin console to load some background pics and display them on the frontend per user session (not on refresh).  I don't think anything is out there so some pointers on how to start building one would be great too.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do it as an extension or simple theme tweaking will be ok for you?

Comment: have a look at this website : [Using JavaScript w/ Cookies to change background](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=67922) or this page used a cookie technique in their code [Changing Page Background Image](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/DHTML_javascript/0596004672_jvdhtmlckbk-chp-12-sect-7.html)

Comment: @Dick Laurent - Anything is cool with me.

Comment: Now that I think about this more...this needs to use the current Magento session. i.e.: change the background when the user's store session is reset.  I'm not interested in duplicating sessions or creating extra cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you.

You can upload images through Magento admin into media storage. Lets say you created a subdir "backgrounds" in there and uploaded various images there. Then all you need to do is add the following code into app/design/frontend/[your-interface]/[your-theme]/template/page/html/header.php

```
<?php

 if(!$background = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getBackground()){
  $img_arr = array();
  if($handle = opendir(Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/media/backgrounds/')){
   while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))){
    if(!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $entry)){
     $img_arr[] = $entry;
    }
   }
   closedir($handle);
  }
  if($img_cnt = count($img_arr)){
   $background = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK).$img_arr[rand(0, $img_cnt-1)]
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBackground($background);
  }
 }

?>
<?php if(isset($background) && $background) : ?>
<style> background:url(<?php echo $background; ?>); </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Did not tested it live. Let me know.

Comment: This code looks promising - I'm gonna try to check that out sometime today and I'll let you know how it works out.  Thanks!